# Time out for external process completion in perl (windows)

Tags: perl

I'm writing a perl program for windows, that runs several SVN commands.

I need to receive the status of the SVN process so i'm using "back ticks".

e.g:

```
{
$COMMAND="blabla...";
$results=`$COMMAND 2>&1`;
parse_results($results);
}
```

Sometimes the process gets stuck, so I need to set timeout to the process.

I tried to use "ALARM" signal but it didn't kill the stuck process.  I receive the indication only if and when the process finishes.

What can I do to deal with processes that don't complete fast enough?

Answer (score 6):

Signals are a unix concept.  Instead, you should use [IPC::Run](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IPC%3a%3aRun).

```
use IPC::Run qw( run timeout );

run [ 'bla', 'arg' ], '>&', \my $results, timeout( 10 )
   or die "bla: $?"
```

Comment: Of course. Basically, you want to run a process in parallel, then wait for the child to end, but for no longer than the timeout. If it's still running then, you kill it.

Comment: thanks ikegami, any code example please? I'm a little discouraged from that issue..